# How do programs acess the internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, browser, port, wifi-transfer

Just out of curiosity, how do programs acess the internet? For example, Icloud is a program by apple that automatically syncs photos, notes, etc. from an apple device to a pc through a wireless connection. Is there a specific function in the C language that allows it to do this? I'm interested in using wireless information like this to control robots, sync computers, etc in the future.

Comment: You should look into Socket programming in C/C++. [Read more](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm).

Comment: For the in-depth gory details of how to do it in C, see Beej's Guide to Network Programming at http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Comment: Wow, where do you want to start, with Ethernet, ARP, TCP/IP, UDP/IP, Standard listening Ports, DHCP, Sockets, DNS, HTTP, routing, firewalls, NAT, session control, SSL, OSI Model, Load balancing, Unix/Linux Servers, Apache, WiFi? This is something for a book, I`m afraid, not a simple answer on Super User.

Comment: It's not impossible to draw a simplified diagram of the network stack and explain the most important tasks of each level (physical, data, network, transport, application). Don't see why this is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very big topic that can not be answered in a simple Q and A format on this site.

If you just want to write programs to talk over the internet, I would recommend learning the basics of programming. As you learn programming you will start to understand how things talk to each other and the whole "client server architecture" and programming with [sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

If you want to learn the nuts and bolts of "How the internet works" and don't really care about the programming side, I recommend listening to the [Security Now!](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm) episodes on "How the internet works". I will link the episodes directly talking about the topic but I do recommend going and listening to [the other episodes](http://www.grc.com/sn/past/2011.htm#310) in between the ones I listed (especially the Q&A episodes following each linked ep.)

- [#309 - How the Internet Works, Part 1](http://media.grc.com/sn/sn-309.mp3)
- [#313 - How The Internet Works: ICMP & UDP](http://media.grc.com/sn/sn-313.mp3)
- [#317 - TCP Part 1 – Getting Connected](http://media.grc.com/sn/sn-317.mp3)
- [#323 - TCP Pt.2 - Attacking TCP](http://media.grc.com/sn/sn-323.mp3)
- [#325 - TCP Pt.3 - Necessary Refinements](http://media.grc.com/sn/sn-325.mp3)